# multicolumn spacing with dotfill in table

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a fill in form, I was trying to use a table to achieve my goal but when I use multicolumn I get three problems

1. The dots don't start at the same location when I use multicolumn in the next cell. The first and 3rd row, for example, do not start at the same location as the 2nd and 4th row.
2. I was trying to make one cell longer while making the other cell shorter (by the same distance) in the same row (3rd row in this case) but that didn't work as you can see...
3. The 1st and 3rd row are not of equal length even though the p columns in row 3 should add up to the same width (0.55+0.05+0.15=0.75) as the multicolumn one in row 1 (0.75).

example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.35\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth} p{0.35\linewidth} }
   Naam & \multicolumn{3}{ p{0.75\linewidth} }{\dotfill} \\
   Datum & \dotfill & Tijd & \dotfill \\
   Straat & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.55\linewidth}}{\dotfill} & Nr & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.15\linewidth}}{\dotfill} \\
   Postcode & \dotfill & Tel & \dotfill \\
  \end{tabular}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 4):

The total width of your `tabular` environment isn't `1\linewidth`, but `1\linewidth+8\tabcolsep, i.e., quite a bit more than`\linewidth`.

As the overall width of the tabular material is supposed to be equal to `\linewidth`, I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment and let LaTeX calculate the relative columnwidths. To set the widths of the four `X` columns suitably, note that 0.6:1.4 = 0.15:0.35.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}
  *{2}{ >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}X } @{}}
   Naam    & \multicolumn{3}{l@{}}{\dotfill} \\
   Datum   & \dotfill & Tijd & \dotfill \\
   Straat  & \dotfill & Nr   & \dotfill \\
   Postcode& \dotfill & Tel  & \dotfill \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but even in your example. It still did not solve my first problem. The dots in the second, third and fourth row do not start at the same "x-coordinate" as the first row. The dots start a little bit earlier in your example in the first row (and also extend a bit further compared to the other rows).

Comment: @LinG - You're right. Not sure what the cause is. It's not the use of `tabularx`; the same issue occurs if the relative column widths are calculated explicitly and four `p` columns are used instead of four `X` columns.

Comment: @Mico How can I make \dotfill automatically?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Please post a new query.