# fill multicolumn cell with dotfill

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I am trying to fill a multicolumn cell with \dotfill. For some reason I do not understand, the dots stop too early. (In normal cells it works fine, but multicolumn cells are reacting differently)
This is what I get:
[image]

I had a look at the solution mentioned in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373081/multicolumn-spacing-with-dotfill-in-table) but with no success. (the @{} didn't make any difference).

Could someone please help me out filling the multicolumn cells with the \dotfill? Thank you!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=1\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1\hsize\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
    $\bigcirc$ Aanvraag offerte & $\bigcirc$ Bestelling\\
    \hline
    Offertebon nr.: \dotfill & Bestelbon nr.: \dotfill \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Firmanaam: \dotfill}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Straat + nr.: \dotfill}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Postcode + Plaats: \dotfill}\\
    \hline      
    Tel.: \dotfill & Fax.: \dotfill \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|@{}l|}{Naam aanvrager: \dotfill}\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\centering\hsize=0.4\hsize}X|>{\centering\hsize=1\hsize}X|>{\centering\hsize=2\hsize}X|>{\centering\hsize=0.6\hsize\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{SteelBlue} Aantal & Referentiecode & Beschrijving wisselstuk & Levertijd\\
    \hline
    & & &\\
    \hline
    & & &\\
    \hline
    & & &\\
    \hline
    & & &\\
    \hline
    & & &\\
    \hline
    & & &\\
    \hline  
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I remove `[H]` from your example document to make it compilable and then compile, I get the following output that elready seems to be the desired result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMqGw.png

Comment: No problem either with this code. Unrelated: if both `X` have the same width, `>{\hsize=1\hsize}` is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, strange. I got that output with that MWE yesterday. But it seems the compiling files were not up to date and still got older code.
I did the update of the MWE and retried. Now I do get the unwanted behaviour...

It turns out that the error comes from the simultanously loading of colortbl (via xcolor) and tabularx.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, `colortbl` is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the desired output you could either go without `colortbl` or, if you need this package for a different table in your document, try th following workaround:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\hsize-2\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    $\bigcirc$ Aanvraag offerte & $\bigcirc$ Bestelling\\
    \hline
    Offertebon nr.: \dotfill & Bestelbon nr.: \dotfill \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\mylength}X|}{Firmanaam: \dotfill}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\mylength}X|}{Straat + nr.: \dotfill}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\mylength}X|}{Postcode + Plaats: \dotfill}\\
    \hline      
    Tel.: \dotfill & Fax.: \dotfill \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\mylength}X|}{Naam aanvrager: \dotfill}\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```